# Paw Not Switching Between Different Google OAuth Users

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, paw-app

I'm trying to test connecting to a Google API on behalf of different Google accounts from the same Google Cloud Project.

I tried using different OAuth client IDs in the OAuth 2.0 as different environmental values but that's not working.

It seems the built-in web browser auto-authorizes for the last Google user who was signed in.

Is there a way for me to force Paw to redo the OAuth user flow?

Comment: Where (browser/android/ios) are you trying this? How is the different account signed in? Does this work if you are just signed in with a 2nd account?

Comment: Using Paw (https://paw.cloud/). My user agent: User-Agent: Paw/3.1.5 (Macintosh; OS X/10.13.0) GCDHTTPRequest.

Because of how Paw works, I don't have an opportunity to log out of the original account.

Comment: This happens because the Paw login window seems to cache the cookie, making it impossible to switch or login to multiple account.

Comment: Same issue for me. Did not find a way to clear the cookie of login window.